# Trouble using pandas read_html() : ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

url = "https://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=068270&amp;page=1"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
res = requests.get(url, verify=True, headers=headers)


with urlopen(url) as doc:
    html = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml') 
    pgrr = html.find('td', class_='pgRR') 
    s = str(pgrr.a['href']).split('=')
    last_page = s[-1]


df = pd.DataFrame()
sise_url = 'http://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=068270'


for page in range(1, int(last_page)+1): 
    page_url = '{}&page={}'.format(sise_url, page)  
    df = df.append(pd.read_html(page_url, encoding='euc-kr', header='0')[0])

df = df.dropna() # 값이 빠진 행을 제거한다.
print(df)
```

I'm having this Value error while crawling the Daily stock data in Naver Finance.
I have no trouble getting the url but if i use the read_html() i have `Value Error:Table not found` issue from the line `df = df.append(pd.read_html(page_url, encoding='euc-kr', header='0')[0])`. Pls give some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't read Korean... however `pd.read_html()` was getting an error page.  Resolved this by `requests.get()` with headers.  Then pass `res.text` to `read_html()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=068270&amp;page=1"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
res = requests.get(url, verify=True, headers=headers)


with urlopen(url) as doc:
    html = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml') 
    pgrr = html.find('td', class_='pgRR') 
    s = str(pgrr.a['href']).split('=')
    last_page = s[-1]


df = pd.DataFrame()
sise_url = 'http://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=068270'

for page in range(1, int(last_page)+1): 
    page_url = '{}&page={}'.format(sise_url, page)  
    res = requests.get(page_url, verify=True, headers=headers)
    df = df.append(pd.read_html(res.text, encoding='euc-kr')[0])
```

Comment: it works. thank you a lot i rly appreciate it so much

Comment: great to have helped - pls accept my answer